# Is it possible to change class name of Jquery autocomplete Menu

Tags: jquery-autocomplete

Is it possible to change class name of Jquery Autocomplete??

default classes are  `.ui-autocomplete` and `.ui-menu`, `.ui-menu-item`  .

So if I want give my own class of styles to the menu, instead of touching `.ui-autocomplete`, is there any way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you:

```
$($('.ac').data("autocomplete").menu.element[0])
    .removeClass('ui-autocomplete ui-menu')
    .addClass('my-autocomplete');
```